# Why is a nested centered flex item with image rendering full width in Firefox?

Tags: css, flexbox

I have some nested `display: flex;` containers. In Chrome/Edge, the `item` div displays as intended, but on Firefox 110.0.1 the `item` takes the whole horizontal space in the `wrapper` (100% width).

What CSS properties will display the containers on Firefox like in Edge, or which browser does it right according to the specs?

#### Microsoft Edge:

[image]

#### Firefox, image 1024×1024 px:

[image]

#### Firefox, image 200×200 px:

[image]

#### Code:

```css
.wrapper {
  outline: aqua solid;
  outline-offset: -3px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* --> */ align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.item {
  outline: magenta solid;
  outline-offset: -13px;
  background-color: maroon;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  outline: gold solid;
  outline-offset: -23px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<p>1024px wide image (scaled to 100px) in 300px wrapper:</p>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    i<img src="https://placekitten.com/1024/1024" alt="image">i
  </div>
</div>

<p>200px wide image (scaled to 100px) in 300px wrapper:</p>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    i<img src="https://placekitten.com/200/200" alt="image">i
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Looks like Firefox does not present well. As I can see flex items is vertically and horizontally center aligned. It must be Firefox bug.

Comment: ok so ive been experimenting for quite a while now and i think im getting somewhere. check this out: https://jsfiddle.net/xs2e4acd/ things get inconsistent only when the img is added... without an image both the system of boxes stay consistent across browsers... i would experiment more but i have some things to do... im posting this here in the hope someone picks up where i left off and gets to the bottom of this. ill be back if i find something else

Comment: @vio Just wanted to mention the same remark. Next interesting detail: it's seems that it's the natural img width what "allocates" its parent (.item) width, see updated sample in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
.wrapper {
  outline: aqua solid;
  outline-offset: -3px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  -webkit-box-align: center; 
  -ms-flex-align: center; 
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}

.item {
  outline: magenta solid;
  outline-offset: -13px;
  background-color: maroon;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  place-content: center;
  place-items: center;
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

img {
  outline: gold solid;
  outline-offset: -23px;
  background-color: red;
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

body {
  background-color: darkgray;
  color: black;
} 

try this if it works :)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, including an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now.